# Fixing a corrupt partition? (RAW data)

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, testdisk

Apologies for misusing some terminology here... I'm attempting to fix a friend's laptop (Dell Inspiron 1545) which was suffering from the error "disk error press any key to restart" on every boot, straight after POST. (Not intermittent, I always received the error).

I tried the drive (250GB SATA) in another machine, and used Window's disk management console to see that it recognised the drive as having 3 partitions.. one was the recovery NTFS partition which seemed perfectly fine, another was the OS partition which was displayed as RAW. It had a drive letter assigned but I could not access the data.

So I tried the program TestDisk which seemed to display the partition as NTFS.. I did nothing but quick scan/save however that has had no effect.

I'm not sure where to go from here.. should I be able to tweak the settings/findings in TestDisk? or should I give up? I can recover the data using Recuva pretty well - but as it's a friend's machine it would be great if a simple fix for the partition table would bring the whole machine back to life as it was.

Does this screenshot help? It shows the findings of TestDisk...
[image]

Many thanks for any pointers you can give :)

*EDIT*

After running a deep scan with TestDisk, it provided the following summary

[image: enter link description here]

Looked slightly odd, but I saved it and now windows doesn't give either the OS or the Recovery partition a drive letter. Does the summary give any suggestion as to how I could proceed? maybe the start/ends are correct but the partitions shouldn't be split in two? Or maybe it's time to give up and format :D

Comment: When it comes to data recovery, nothing is ever simple. That said, I've had pretty good luck with `TestDisk` ability to recover lost partitions.

Comment: When using TestDisk - do you just stick to the semi-automated Scan/Save process - or is there anything else if that fails to work? I haven't done the deep scan so maybe I need to try that first..

Comment: I did deep scan - it takes a while, but seems to find partitions reliably even if you dd start of disk with 0's.

Comment: Thanks, have added further comments in the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was probably overthinking this issue a tad. All I had to do was run a `chkdsk /f` and it fixed the problem, drive now appears with files accessible :)

Answer (score 0):

I've been consistently successful with Spinrite. As long as it's not a mechanical problem, it works really well.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - I should have maybe said in the question but I'm not looking to pay for any solution but just stick to the free options. It's more an educational exercise really :)

Comment: Please let us know how it goes, I haven't been able to find an alternative free solution..

Comment: Pedro - please see my answer, maybe mine was a very simple case but chkdsk did the trick!